# How can I make this Advanced Custom Field Save & Store local json work?

Tags: child-theme, advanced-custom-fields, json

I call this function from theme function.php and ACF still will not save local json. The `acf-json` folder is 0755 and correct user/group.

```
<?php 
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
$plugin = '/wp-content/plugins/acfpro/acf.php';
$storage = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/lib/acf-json';
if ( is_plugin_active( '$plugin' ) ) {

function my_acf_init() {

    acf_update_setting('save_json', $storage );

}

add_action('acf/init', 'my_acf_init');


add_filter('acf/settings/save_json', 'my_acf_json_save_point');

function my_acf_json_save_point( $path ) {

    // update path
    $path = $storage;


    // return
    return $path;

}

add_filter('acf/settings/load_json', 'my_acf_json_load_point');

    function my_acf_json_load_point( $paths ) {

    // remove original path (optional)
        unset($paths[0]);


    // append path
        $paths[] = $storage;


    // return
        return $paths;

    }
}
```

Comment: `get_stylesheet_directory()` [does not contain a trailing slash](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory). Also, the question is off-topic because it does not contain any WordPress code (e. g., action or hook).

Comment: No wordpress code? Are you serious? ACF is a WP plugin. ```add_filter``` is a Wordpress function. And, ```add_action('acf/init', 'my_acf_init');``` I guess you missed that?

Comment: Questions concerning third-party plugins and themes [are off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: "What topics can I ask about here?
WordPress Stack Exchange is for WordPress developers and administrators to ask questions about:

theme and plugin development
development and management best practices
server configuration for WordPress...

Comment: I understand where you may imply it's off topic, @MaxYudin. There are many other ACF related questions and because the plugin is quite popular, someone who has integrated with a child theme may see the issue and I thank you for spotting the trailing slash.